# Windows 10 can't run .exe from network share

Tags: windows

I had a two Windows servers that sharing files SERVER1 (Windows 2008), SERVER2 (Windows2012).

On one share I've got .exe file which is very simple application - simple.exe. It works great while it is placed on SERVER1 - I can run it directly from SERVER1, from Windows 7 workstation machine, and from Windows 10. 
When I'm copying this .exe to SERVER2 share - It still works on SERVER2, Windows 7 machines, but I had huge problems to run it on Windows10 machines. And here is the most strangest part for me:

- simple.exe file can be run on Windows 10 directly after reboot
- after closing the app - it can't be run it shows error about .NET (described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2715633/shim-errors-for-the--net-framework-version-and-platform-support)
- after closing error message simple.exe file is not visible on the network share for that particular Windows 10 machine (while it is existing on share, and possible to run from server and windows 7 machines)
- to make it visile again proces explore.exe must be killed on Windows 10

Environment is AD based, access right to the exe file are exactly the same on both SERVER1 and SERVER2. simple.exe file runs ok on Windows10 always when it is placed on local drive.

UAC on Windows 10 is disabled, SERVER2 is added in "Internet Options", EnableLinked... registry entry is added.

Disabling Firewall on both sides does't help
Disabling AV on both sides doesn't work

I've catch errors at Event Viewer:

```
Application: app1.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.SetNamesAndVersion(System.String, System.Reflection.Assembly, Boolean)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(System.String, Boolean)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(System.String, Boolean)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.ConfigurationManagerInternal.System.Configuration.Internal.IConfigurationManagerInternal.get_ExeProductName()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Initializer()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.CreateSetting(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Properties()
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(System.String)
   at CodeComparator.Properties.Settings.get_login()
   at CodeComparator.HomePage..ctor()
   at CodeComparator.Program.Main()

Faulting application name: app1.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a27c260
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.15063.726, time stamp: 0x32774c02
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000ecbb2
Faulting process id: 0x38a8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d36f93614d1cf8
Faulting application path: I:\pathto\app1.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 5df493a4-d442-475e-8b85-1cd8f9d13acf
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Application: app1.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 73A516E9 (738D0000) with exit code 80131506.

 Faulting application name: app1.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a27c260
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.2115.0, time stamp: 0x59af88f2
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x001816e9
Faulting process id: 0x3850
Faulting application start time: 0x01d36f9364d4f9ba
Faulting application path: I:\pathto\app1.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 31b42ecf-1b01-4e98-8bd0-f4032585bb26
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

To be more funny: when trying to debug app1.exe with WinDBG - it runs well after 2 times it throws exception:

```
ModLoad: 00000000`5df20000 00000000`5df93000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64win.dll
(22e8.28f0): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ff8`cea071b8 cc              int     3

ModLoad: 00000000`744e0000 00000000`746a2000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll
(22e8.28f0): WOW64 breakpoint - code 4000001f (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
ntdll_779f0000!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b:
77a9db9b cc              int     3
```

Any ideas appreciated, since I'm running out of options.

Comment: Sounds like AV, a .NET conflict or offline caching to me. Try to disable AV and caching, look into the (application) eventlos for .NET errors.

Comment: With disabled AV, and Windows firewall on both - Windows 10 machine and SERVER2 - still the same behavior.

Comment: ... offline caching?

Comment: I've edited original question with more details.

Comment: Your kernel is choking on this? It's going to be really hard to determine why without knowing what the application is supposed to do or what it is.

Comment: This is ery simple app. doesn't do anything special. The problem exist only windows 10 machines, but the behaviour is really strange, especially when the file is not visible on the share for explore.exe on Windows 10.

It works well when it is located on local drive or when it is running on share on W2008 server.